# Many to many relationship with Mysql & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, many-to-many

Let' say I Have 2 tables, webpage table, and a keywords table. It's a many to many relationshiop, right? One webpage can contain more than one keyword, and one keyword can be part of more than one webpage.

Webpage table contain id field as PK, and few other fields.  Keywords table contain id as a PK, and also a few other fields. Third table, a child table, should contain id fields from both parent tables? Is it posible to track many to many relationship, with no foreign keys, just declaring this 2 id fields in child table as UNIQUE?

With or without FK's, when inserting new keywords for example through PHP, how should I refer, to which webpage this new keyword belongs, webpage id in a webpage table, or a id in a child table?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use foreign keys?  They seem appropriate in this case

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this...

**Table1**

```
Table_WebPage
PageID, PageName, Url,...........
```

**Table2**

```
Table_KeyWords
WordID, Word, .........
```

**Table3**

```
Table_PageKeyWords
ID, PageID, WordID
```

Dont know why you want to do it without FK, Having FKs will enforce the data integrity and stop garbage data coming into your tables.